# How to assign a value to a global variable inside a function?

Tags: ruby

I have a function where I get input from a user

```
def get_single_argument(argument,name)

    begin
        puts "Type #{name}: "
        argument = STDIN.gets.chomp
        puts "#{name} --> #{argument} OK??"

        happy = STDIN.gets.downcase.chomp

    end until (happy.strip[0,1].to_s =='y' )
end
```

but when I call this function where the argument is a global variable the global variable is not updated. How can I assign a value to a global variable which name is passed as a function argument? $web_url is '' - empty string.

```
       $web_url =''
       puts "url je:#{$web_url}"

       get_single_argument($web_url,"web url")
       puts "url je:#{$web_url}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.replace` inside your method. Instead of

```
argument = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

you can write

```
argument.replace STDIN.gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Instead make `get_single_argument` return the value:

```
def get_single_argument(name)
    happy = "no"
    until happy.strip[0,1].to_s =='y'
        puts "Type #{name}: "
        argument = STDIN.gets.chomp
        puts "#{name} --> #{argument} OK??"

        happy = STDIN.gets.downcase.chomp
    end 
    argument
end
```

and

```
web_url = get_single_argument("web url")
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to this line:

```
argument = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

the local variable `argument` and the global variable `$web_url` did refer to the same object in computer memory. After the line is executed, the variable `argument` now refers to a different object than `$web_url` refers.

As Howard mentioned, using `argument.replace(..)` will modify the String object in memory without breaking the link between the variable and the object in memory.

Generally, a better way is not to use the global variable, but have the method return the user input.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I still didn't understand why after the line is executed it refers to some other object.

Comment: Because you told `argument` to refer to something else when you used the assignment ( = ) operator. If you wrote `argument = 1` instead, would you still expect `argument` and `$web_url` to refer to the same object?

Comment: Oh, ok I wasn't clear. I do not understand why in my code after assignment to argument the value of global variable is not changed.